# How can I prevent Outlook 2010 from trying to authenticate with the Domain Controller's Active Directory?

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, windows-7, exchange, outlook-2010, windows-8

Windows 7 and Windows 8 64 bit, Outlook 2010, Windows Server 2008R2.

Basically, our Outlook tries to authenticate the user's email credentials with the DC. Problem is, we use hosted exchange through Rackspace, and while it's the same username (firstname.lastname), the pass is different because email passwords and domain passwords are obviously different due to domain passes needing to be changed every 3 months.

We do NOT want to set them to the same pass, and can NOT change our login or email address or domain name anywhere.

So, how can I tell Outlook to avoid going to the DC?

Answer (score 1):

when you configure the account in outlook, you can specify the incoming server of that account.

You need to point your exchange server configuration to rackspace's servers, and not to your domain.

In the link below, in the rackspace support, you can find a guide to how to configure it in your outlook.

http://www.rackspace.com/apps/support/portal/5912

Regards